# In Roslyn, what is the difference between Names and Identifiers?

Tags: roslyn

In Roslyn, there are several factory methods on `SyntaxFactory` that are creating names and identifiers. For instance:

- `SF.Identifier`
- `SF.ParseName`
- `SF.IdentifierName`

When should I use which? And what are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SF.Identifier` creates a `SyntaxToken`, so you should use it when you need a token (often for the declaration of something).

The other two both return a `NameSyntax`, which represent a reference to something. The difference is that `IdentifierName` is the simplified form that has just one identifier, whereas ParseName can also handle qualified and generic names (which can also be created directly using helpers off `SyntaxFactory` as well if you know that you want them.